# GUI - visualize table filtering speed

Tags: gui-design, mac-os-x, progress

I'd like to present a UI element suggesting progress of a string filtering process.

Filtering:

We have a growing table/list of strings. We're filtering all the strings using some rule and filling another "filtered" table.

Currently I show a simple text saying "Checked NNN lines out of MMM".

I'd like to show also some graphical representation.

Simple progress bar showing NNN ratio in MMM doesn't look good because it always oscillates near the right edge, and looks almost full. Consider original table of 4M lines which gets 100K of new unfiltered lines - less then 3% of the total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So is your goal:

1. To show the user that he/she only sees a really small percentage of the total set.

or

2. To just show the user that there is a filtered set

I think you mean 1., otherwise the X out of Y bar would be enough in my opinion.

A log(aritmic) scale could be one of the solutions.

But maybe better to use the image and emphasize it with the numbers in text.

[image: Something like this]

Comment: I forgot to mention it in the text: visually separating the two 'results' really helps, as shown in the drawing.

Comment: I want to give a user the feeling of time he'll wait till the original record set will be processed and/or to see that the original grows faster then the filtering happens. In other words speed of processing and current state of completion.

Comment: Logarithmic scale and color coding are a couple of very interesting ideas. If I make progress bar tri-color (checked and accepted / checked and thrown away / to be checked) would it make sense for the user or just a mess ?

Comment: Hi LiMar, I think you could try making some concepts out of this and just ask some people (preferably clients). It's really personal what people like most. But I think this might be a good solution to make a distinction between the three. Or use indicators like stripes or dots. Or a combination of the two.